# Add a textview below recyclerview in drawer layout

Tags: android

I have the below xml , I want to place a text view above the `recyclerview` and below `recyclerview`, but its showing wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/testv"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        />



    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

update

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.mohamadmouazen.lebgame.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" /> -->

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Show the full xml code please.

Comment: share with us all your layout. Also a picture who its looks will help.

Comment: Can you please attach an image?

Comment: @tahsinrupam please check now

Comment: Is the `RecyclerView` meant to be in your drawer, or is it the main content?

Comment: @Mike M. Main content but if add the recyxlerview outside the drawer it disapear

Comment: Everything you want in the main content needs to go in a single `ViewGroup` - e.g., a vertical `LinearLayout` - that's listed before the `NavigationView` inside the `DrawerLayout` tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386157/wrong-size-and-click-behavior-for-views-in-drawerlayout

Answer (score 1):

> I want to place a text view above the recycler view and below recycler
>   view

Try this layout:

use a `Linearlayout` with vertical orientation inside your `DrawerLayout`

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAbove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="New Text above" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBelow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="New Text Below" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/overview_floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/overview_coordinator_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationdrawer_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The second text didnt appear also the floating bar in the incluse appbar also disapeared

Comment: try wrapping the  linear layout inside `nestedscrollview` ...i have edited the answer.

Comment: @Moudiz  i have edited the full code...with you app bar layout included in same layout..

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work i dont know how to explain but its dipalying wrong